# NodeJS Sequelize DataTypes.DOUBLE(10,2) is returning integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

DataTypes.DOUBLE(10,2) or DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,2) returns integer if there is no decimal value after ".". Only returns decimal if there is any value other then zero.

Migration

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('properties', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      serial: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      type: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      base_fare: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE(10,2)
      },
      current_fare : {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE(10,2)
      },
      tenant_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      booking_id : {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      building_id : {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('properties');
  }
};
```

Model

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Property extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
     // Removed for readability

    }
  }

  Property.init({
    serial: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    base_fare: DataTypes.DOUBLE(10,2),
    current_fare: DataTypes.DOUBLE(10,2),
    tenant_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    booking_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    building_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Property',
    timestamps: false,
    omitNull: false,
    name: {
      singular: 'property',
      plural: 'properties'
    },
    underscored: true
  });
  return Property;
};
```

Sample Data

```
{
            "id": 11,
            "serial": 19,
            "type": "",
            "name": "Room",
            "base_fare": 2400,
            "current_fare": null,
            "tenant_id": null,
            "booking_id": null,
            "building_id": 1
},
{
            "id": 12,
            "serial": 19,
            "type": "",
            "name": "Room",
            "base_fare": 2400.5,
            "current_fare": null,
            "tenant_id": null,
            "booking_id": null,
            "building_id": 1
}
```

I want my "base_fare" to output 2400.00 ( fill the zeros ) if there is no zero or other digits. The numbers are automatically getting converted to integer if there is no non zero digits after decimal point. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fault of *sequelize* but **javascript** itself.
The only way to display as much zeros after delimeter as you want is to convert **number** into **string**.

The easiest way would be to use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.
In case of *sequelize* you either have to override [getter](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/) of `base_fare`
or just **map** query result with:

```js
let result = await ... //here is the model query  
result = result.map((x) => ({
    ...x,
    base_fare: x.base_fare.toFixed(2)
})
);
```

or

```js
let result = await ... //here is the model query  
result.forEach( (x) => x.base_fare = x.base_fare.toFixed(2) );
```